# Is it possible to make interfaces with BaseContract as a type?

Tags: typescript, ethereum, ethers.js

Is it possible in ethers typescript to set a class variable to what object this functio would return?  `new ethers.Contract(V2_FACTORY_ADDRESSES[ChainId.MAINNET], CONTRACTABI.uniswap.factory, ProviderSingleton.getWebSocket())`

Im setting the object to Contract in my class but im getting this type `"hardhat/internal/hardhat-network/stack-traces/model"` as the only type of Contract i can accesss in the system. Im thinking theres some sort of NPM tool i need to use that would expose it to me like typechain, but even when using that it didnt return the same type of contract.

My overall goal is to create an exchange class that would be able to access both the factory and router contract, and even further just be able to set a function up in the class called "getPair" which i would just call the appropriate contract....but i need to get passed this part first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [ethereum-abi-types-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereum-abi-types-generator) npm package. for each development tool there is a different cli command:

```
{
  "name": "examples",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "web3-example": "abi-types-generator './abi-examples/fake-contract-abi.json' --output='./web3/fake-contract-example/generated-typings' --name=fake-contract",
    "web3-token-abi": "abi-types-generator './abi-examples/token-abi.json' --output='./web3/uniswap-example/generated-typings' --name=token-contract",
    "web3-uniswap-exchange-abi": "abi-types-generator './abi-examples/uniswap-exchange-abi.json' --output='./web3/uniswap-example/generated-typings' --name=uniswap-exchange-contract",
    "web3-uniswap-factory-abi": "abi-types-generator './abi-examples/uniswap-factory-abi.json' --output='./web3/uniswap-example/generated-typings' --name=uniswap-factory-contract",
    "web3-uniswap": "npm run web3-token-abi && npm run web3-uniswap-exchange-abi && npm run web3-uniswap-factory-abi",
    "ethers-example": "abi-types-generator './abi-examples/fake-contract-abi.json' --output='./ethers/fake-contract-example/generated-typings' --name=fake-contract --provider=ethers",
    "ethers-token-abi": "abi-types-generator './abi-examples/token-abi.json' --output='./ethers/uniswap-example/generated-typings' --name=token-contract --provider=ethers",
    "ethers-uniswap-exchange-abi": "abi-types-generator './abi-examples/uniswap-exchange-abi.json' --output='./ethers/uniswap-example/generated-typings' --name=uniswap-exchange-contract --provider=ethers",
    "ethers-uniswap-factory-abi": "abi-types-generator './abi-examples/uniswap-factory-abi.json' --output='./ethers/uniswap-example/generated-typings' --name=uniswap-factory-contract --provider=ethers",
    "ethers-uniswap": "npm run ethers-token-abi && npm run ethers-uniswap-exchange-abi && npm run ethers-uniswap-factory-abi",
    "ethers-v5-example": "abi-types-generator './abi-examples/fake-contract-abi.json' --output='./ethers_v5/fake-contract-example/generated-typings' --name=fake-contract --provider=ethers_v5",
    "ethers-v5-token-abi": "abi-types-generator './abi-examples/token-abi.json' --output='./ethers_v5/uniswap-example/generated-typings' --name=token-contract --provider=ethers_v5",
    "ethers-v5-uniswap-exchange-abi": "abi-types-generator './abi-examples/uniswap-exchange-abi.json' --output='./ethers_v5/uniswap-example/generated-typings' --name=uniswap-exchange-contract --provider=ethers_v5",
    "ethers-v5-uniswap-factory-abi": "abi-types-generator './abi-examples/uniswap-factory-abi.json' --output='./ethers_v5/uniswap-example/generated-typings' --name=uniswap-factory-contract --provider=ethers_v5",
    "ethers-v5-uniswap": "npm run ethers-token-abi && npm run ethers-uniswap-exchange-abi && npm run ethers-uniswap-factory-abi",
    "hardhat-example": "abi-types-generator hardhat"
  }
}
```

you give the abi.json file location and then it will create types in output folder.

Comment: I ended up using Type-chain which did exactly what i intended but your answer is correct. Only issue was that when i tried to use this it needed to used with either ethers 4 or 5 and im using ethers 6. Thank You for your  help